# no reputation increase on my stackoverflow account

Tags: support

I am not getting +2 reputation for every approved edit. I can see in my activity that all the edits that i suggested are approved. plz let me know, why is it so. is there some limit on edits??

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there's a limit of 1000 rep from edits.

Comment: is there any way to know the limit?? thanks. Plz post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: the limit is enforced on monthly edits??

Comment: @SAK It's not monthly. That's a *total* limit.